# Loading component inside another component using @input in angular

Tags: angular

This is an Angular 4.x question.

I have a header component which is used everywhere in the app. I want to be able to pass it another component so it can render it. I want it to be simple like:

```
<app-header
    [Component]  = "myComponent"
></app-header>
```

This *myComponent* can belong to the module the header is being loaded in.
Lots of developers have used different methods (some of them deprecated in newer version of angular 4.4.3). I am trying to do it in the simplest and cleanist possible way. Since my modules are loaded *lazily* i cannot put them in the root Module as 'entryComponents' and thats where its getting tough for me.

I have tried NgComponentOutlet (https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) but its not working for me.

I have also tried the Dynamic Component Loading (DML) ( https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader ) and thats not working either. It requires me to add the dynamic component in the 'entryComponents' of the root Module.

Any help please?

Comment: Your `myCompanent` has  a selector like: `app-my-component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the solution i used its as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector       : 'app-header',
    templateUrl    : `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dynamicComponent"></ng-container>`,
})
export class HeaderDesktopComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() component: any     = null;

    dynamicComponent = null;

    ngOnInit() {
        if ( component ) {
            this.dynamicComponent = this.component;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the other module's template:

```
<app-header [component]="myComponent"></app-header>
```

And in code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myComponent = MyCustomHeaderComponent;
}
```

The key is to declare *MyCustomHeaderComponent* in the 'entryComponents' of the module its part of.

**Update:**
Have also found a good package to handle dynamic components with @Input and @Output: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component

Answer (score 0):

You should use Your `myComponent`'s selector in template of `app-header`...

Let's consider that You have `HeaderComponent` in its template You should include Your `app-my-component` like: template: `<app-my-component></app-my-component>`

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. MyComponent is actually dynamic and will be different in each module. I have found a way but the component has to be put in 'entryComponents' in the module.